# How to use SADD in Redis

Tags: database, redis, relationship

I found this nice example and I am trying to make relations between hashes and then get some data.

```
# Here are my categories
> hmset category:1 name cinema  ... more fields ...
> hmset category:2 name music   ... more fields ...
> hmset category:3 name sports  ... more fields ...
> hmset category:4 name nature  ... more fields ...

# Here are my users
> hmset user:1 name Jack   ... more fields ...
> hmset user:2 name John   ... more fields ...
> hmset user:3 name Julia  ... more fields ...

# Let's establish the many-to-many relationship
# Jack likes cinema and sports
# John likes music and nature
# Julia likes cinema, music and nature

# For each category, we keep a set of reference on the users
> sadd category:1:users 1 3
> sadd category:2:users 2 3
> sadd category:3:users 1
> sadd category:4:users 2 3

# For each user, we keep a set of reference on the categories
> sadd user:1:categories 1 3
> sadd user:2:categories 2 4
> sadd user:3:categories 1 2 4


# Categories of Julia
> smembers user:3:categories
1) "1"
2) "2"
3) "4"
```

What if I would like to get the name of categories?

```
smembers user:3:categories name
```

Didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it in one roundtrip is to use:

```
SORT user:3:categories BY nosort GET category:*->name
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I added cost field but this line didnt work.Can I print two field at the same time?

sort user:3:category GET category:*->name category:*->cost

Comment: Yes, just add another GET, i.e.: `sort user:3:category GET category:*->name GET category:*->cost` (and read the doc at http://redis.io/commands/sort)

Comment: thanks again.Another question;
"hmset user:1 name Jack
hmset category:1 name music
hmset instrument:1 name guitar
sadd user:1:category 1
sadd category:1:instrument 1"
So in this case if I want to get user's instrument how should write my command? this didnt work
sort User:1:Category:1:Instrument Get Category*:->Instrument